# Refresh data while keeping scroll position with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I keep my scroll position when I refresh my data in my RecyclerView ?
The problem in my code, is that the data I get is coming from an API, and now when I refresh my data, I use the `clear()` method to delete the current data, and I use a `getData ()` method to retrieve the new data.

***getData method :***

```
        private void getData() {
        JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url_get, response -> {
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Category cat = new Category();
                    cat.setId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                    cat.setCategory(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    cat.setPvisited(jsonObject.getString("person_visited"));
                    cat.setCompany(jsonObject.getString("company"));
                    cat.setDate(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                    category.add(cat);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            adapterPush(category);
            refresh.setRefreshing(false);
        }, error -> {

        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);
    }
```

***category detail :***

```
        private final ArrayList<Category> category = new ArrayList<>();
```

***onRefresh method :***

```
        @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        category.clear();
        getData();
    }
```

I think the getdata() method has a problem, when I remove

> `category.clear();`

of my code, the data is added to the string but the position still returns to the beginning.
Or maybe I should used other thing like a refresh method rather than `clear()` ?

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag. That tag is used for the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

```java
category.clear();
recyclerview.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: On my side, the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method does not work. I went to see the documentation, and I don't think I can add it to my code? Also, how do I refresh my data without the `getData()` function